# Data gets corrupted on form send, =\r\n introduced in the data every 75 characters?

Tags: django, forms, google-app-engine, blobstore, django-nonrel

I'm working on a project in Django nonrel, on Google App Engine, though I have a feeling  my problem has nothing to do with either of these directly .

I have a hidden field in one of the models that is defined like so:

```
models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True,default="{}")
```

The field is meant to receive JSON data from a widget in my admin, and in the client its value changes properly.

*(Which data is being sent is irrelevant to my problem - whatever string is in the field value is being corrupted)*

**The problem is** - 
when I look at the data as passed to the django save function , I see that every 75 characters I get `=\r\n` inside the data string. This effectively breaks the string, rendering my data useless. I have no idea where this is coming from, or what causes this.

More interesting points:

- The admin form has `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, since I use GAE blobstore to upload a file in that form
- I'm using [django-filetransfers](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers) to facilitate working with the blobstore
- I've checked the request going out of the browser, the data going out is clean
- Django saves the data in the model as UTF8

I haven't found anything remotely close to my problem on google...

Does anyone have a solution? Or maybe a direction on where to start looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is a result of [this bug in Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749)

I found my solution here: [Encoding problem in app engine when submitting multipart/form-data forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624226/encoding-problem-in-app-engine-when-submitting-multipart-form-data-forms)

The problem was solved using Andres Bossard middleware fix in that thread