# why are there =\r\n characters coming from my textarea?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

In my form i have:

```
<textarea id="styled" name="content"></textarea>
```

before submitting the form i cut and paste the following into the text area:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

When I retrieve the value on google app engine:

```
ImageUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    content_i = self.request.get("content", None)

#content_i is:
u'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa=\r\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Comment: Sounds like it isn't being decoded properly.

Comment: So their bug not mine right? On the development server it was \r\r\n. on live it's =\r\n. Currently I'm doing this after to fix: content_i = cgi.escape(content_i)
                    content_i = "<br />".join(content_i.replace("=\r", "\r").replace("\r\r", "\r").splitlines())

Comment: I would see if it's coming in as QP by trying characters such as "=" first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749). Though this might solve your problem -> [@AndreBrossards Middleware  Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624226/encoding-problem-in-app-engine-when-submitting-multipart-form-data-forms)