# Why am I getting this UnicodeEncodeError in production but not in development? App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know this has been asked many times before and I may deserve downvotes for the question
but I tried a lot of things with no success.

My application is in production.

I'm getting this error:

```
2012-10-03 15:08:29.385 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128) Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/python27_runtim
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 Traceback (most recent call last):
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 response = self._internal_error(e)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 return handler.dispatch()
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 return method(*args, **kwargs)
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sigs-enlanube/1.362200469572800834/SIGS.py", line 231, in post
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 descripcion = str(self.request.get('txtDescripcion')).decode('utf-8')
E 2012-10-03 15:08:29.447 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the line mentioned in the stacktrace:
[image]

I'm using jinja2. This is the text entered in the text area.

[image]

This is how the page starts:
[image]

and this is the text-area code:

[image]

I don understand why I get this error in production because when tested in localhost everything is OK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your HTML page UTF-8 encoded? Why you need the str()? Why do you decode after the str() and not after the get?

Comment: @voscausa how should I properly make the decoding? This way: decode(self.request.get('stuff'),utf-8)?

Comment: Here is a good article: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python. I think you have to code : descripcion =  self.request.get('txtDescripcion').decode('utf-8')

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624226/encoding-problem-in-app-engine-when-submitting-multipart-form-data-forms

Comment: @robertking thanks Robert. Apparently it's something related to multipart/form-data forms. I'll try some suggestions later.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to a bug, see [Encoding problem in app engine when submitting multipart/form-data forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624226/encoding-problem-in-app-engine-when-submitting-multipart-form-data-forms)

```
>>> import quopri
>>> t = unicode(quopri.decodestring('=CD'), 'iso_8859-2')
>>> print t
Í
```